# Manually controlling the ROS driver from Python

Tags: ros, python, roscore, ros-noetic

What is the best approach to launch a ROS file? Do I need to check that `roscore` is running before running it?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Your question needs more information. For example, what do you mean by "ros driver"? About the `roscore`, it is started automatically if you execute a `roslaunch`. Can you please elaborate more on your use case?

Comment: I modified my question to clarify my question.

Comment: it deos not start the roscore, I need to start the roscore first and then launch the file.

Comment: That's abnormal. Please mention more about the installation and design/configuration of your system. Is your ROS running across multiple machines? As I suggested earlier, the use case should be explained in detail.

Comment: The usecase is an IMU system for a robot, it is running in one computer only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question, you can launch some files with [roslaunch python API](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage) and `ROSLaunch()` call may fail when there's no running ROS Master node available.

Hope this helps.